# NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID after update to Chrome 44

Tags: google-chrome

After Chrome was updated to the latest version, 44, my site does no longer load. Site URL: www.vintagevibes.nl

The error message:NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID is shown.

Full text:

Your connection is not private

'Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.vintagevibes.nl (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"

I have tried all other browsers and they work fine, as well as older versions of Chrome. Same problem occurs in the latest beta of Chrome 45.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it may be related to [this](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-44-sending-https-header-by-mistake-breaking-web-applications-everywhere/).

Comment: Found an excellent fix for this problem! Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Read all about the problem here:**

https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-44-sending-https-header-by-mistake-breaking-web-applications-everywhere/

Download this plugin to fix it fast: 
http://www.wdc.me/chrome-ssl-fix.zip

1. Upload chrome-ssl-fix.php to the /wp-content/plugins/chrome-ssl-fix/ directory
2. Activate the plugin through the 'Plugins' menu in WordPress
3. Site fixed :-)

Oh, don't forget to buy the plugin developer (Stefan Vasiljevic)  a beer for this excellent solution.
Donate trough Paypal right from your WordPress dashboard.